# Should "give me an example of..." questions be closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Related: [How is this off-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348053/how-is-this-off-topic)

My question is similar to the linked question but more general. It seems like questions in the form "can someone give me an example of *X*?" are often closed as off-topic for being recommendation requests. Is this actually a correct interpretation of the policy? Should questions in that form actually be closed and, if so, what reason should be used?

Comment: As with all of these <s>complaints</s> discussions, if it is apparent that the user is not asking for an off-site resource, edit the question to rephrase it.

Comment: The question might also be too broad, depending on how extensive of an example they want.

Comment: Closely related: [*Is example (not code) requesting in some situations on-topic?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336989/275185)

Comment: if it fits a close reason, sure. Otherwise a downvote will suffice if you think it isn't useful or is of low quality/research. I don't think those specific types of questions are off topic for off site resource reason, but they may be for others. "How do i do X" is on topic, and "Can you give me an example of X" is just the former in disguise.

Comment: Yes - give it a quick glance.  Like most, (all?), questions beginning with 'Consider....), it's almost certainly going to be off-topic or closeable for another reason, but you gotta check:(

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260) at SE.SE meta

Comment: Is 'some examples' the same as 'an example'? in my interpretation, the former is requesting dozens of answers, while the latter requests just one single answer which can answer the question.

Comment: when there are dozens of er [Julia Roberts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281787/165773) out there willing to try their luck at "just one example plz" question these become the same I'm afraid @musea

Comment: If *example* is contextual synonym for *tutorial* - it's off-topic. If it's about understanding some obscure language/library/etc feature I would say it's a perfectly valid question. For example *"I heard/read that X **usually** Y. But I don't see how it's possible that X not Y. Could you give an example of X not Y?"*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends on the question.  Here's an example of a good example question:

"I was reading the documentation on LinkedHashMap.  It has a mode where the items are reordered so the most recently retrieved item is at the front of the list.  Can someone give me an example of where that would be used?"

Its a question that has an answer (in this case, an LRU cache), a reasonable scope, and is looking for an explanation of something. Anyone closing a question like that would be wrong.

Comment: People point and laugh at those who flag word filter questions with profanities as sample input as offensive based on the profanities alone, and, without blinking, vote to close questions asking for examples with the same close reason regardless of context.

Comment: "Give me an example of **literally anything** that uses [some broad topic]" isn't a reasonably scoped question.  That question has a *huge* scope.  That's exactly the type of question that *isn't* appropriate.